# Why illegal constant names doesn't throw errors using define()?

Tags: php, constants

From the [`Constants`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) manual:

> The name of a constant follows the same rules as any label in PHP. A
>   valid constant name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular
>   expression, it would be expressed thusly:
>   [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*

But:

```
 define ("0000X" , 1);
```

Doesn't throws any errors nor notices and `defined` returns true:

```
var_dump ( defined ( "0000X" ) ); // true
```

Sure, when trying to use this constant, it yields:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'X' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in [...][...] on line 3

`Const`, on the other hand

```
const 0000X = 2;
```

throws an error on its initialization, avoiding its wrong use:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '0000' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in [...][...] on line 1

In case anyone want to see this in action:

[Live example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1fa849e2266f76607fcd9abfd3542c43de07ee4)

Comment: Just so you know `define` and `const` are evaluated in very different locations, `const` is evaluated at compile time(that's why you can't set it to a function definition or whatever), while `define` is evaluated at execution(which is why `define('START_TIME', microtime(true));` works perfectly fine, despite it giving different results (almost)every time it's run). The code for define doesn't do anything to validate your constant(I've no idea why it doesn't, but it doesn't).

Comment: `define` shouldn't validate the input. At the point when you want to use (invalid) tokens, you'll fail. Everything's fine and the world is OK, with everything being completely alright and in sync with Universe.

Comment: I believe you can still use invalid constants defined with `define` using `constant()`. Not that that's a bright idea...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation of the parser engine. When used in `const` you're inherently limited by the tokenization of the code, being that a token starting with numbers is treated as a number by definition, as required by many mathematical expressions. This is why you see the `unexpected T_LNUMBER` error in that usage.

Since `define` is a language construct taking a string as a parameter, it doesn't err on the tokenization, and as such can parse and execute this just fine, while its usage still fails on the tokenization in the end. It does seem like a bug that `define` does not check its argument for usability to me, but is more probably a historic quirk in PHP that noone dares to fix not knowing what might break. You could file a bug report for it and see what the PHP devs have to say.